# How to flag comments answering to already deleted comments?

Tags: support, flagging, comments

To take my part in keeping this site clean, I am trying to flag comments when I feel it is appropriate. For instance, [in this case](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/99777/is-it-safe-to-use-same-key-pair-to-encrypt-and-sign), there is a comment "*Sure. It's a common mistake.*" answering to previous and deleted comments:

- The OP did a mistake in the title ("decrypt" instead of "sign"),
- StackzOfZtuff edited it and put a comment to explain the modification,
- The OP thanks him,
- StackzOfZtuff then leaved the above comments, "*Sure. It's a common mistake.*".

Now that the whole previous comment discussion has been deleted, I thought it was sensible to flag this single lasting comment as obsolete (it seems just meaningless and out of any context as it is now).

However the flag was declined.

Was it wrong to flag this comment? Does this comment have any use yet? Did I flag it the wrong way? Should there be another flag reason like "I am flagging this comment as: answering to an already deleted comment"?

Comment: naw, that's a good flag - its just rather low priority. So as long as you don't flood the queue with dozens of obsolete comment flags, everyone would be appreciative :-)

Comment: @AviD: I do not think I can be considered as a so-called "flooder": after nearly one year of active service, I will only soon manage to reach the Deputy badge awarding the 80 flags ;), but as per my understanding the flags being anonymous, I suppose mine was lost in such a flooding a wave :).

Comment: I see quite a lot of your flags that I would consider better than some that come through - don't worry if there is the odd one that someone rejects. It could be because their point of view is that the comment is still valid, or maybe they clicked the wrong button (yep, even mods are humans)

Comment: looks like a good flag to me

Comment: Looks like it is mod-unanimous (well except for @Jefff, but we don't count him), but I wasn't saying you WERE flooding (or that anybody was), just that one *shouldn't* ;-)